# sqlite search use uppercase and lower case

Tags: android

I want to select records from sqlite3 database by string matching. I use '=' in the where clause.

I input a paramecter is "NUM" and I want get record have "num". What query I do ?

Comment: Do Google search ....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at these tutorials http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_func_ucase.asp and http://alvinalexander.com/sql/sql-select-case-insensitive-query-queries-upper-lower

The SQL standard way to perform case insensitive queries is to use the SQL upper() or lower() functions, like this:

```
select * from myTable where upper(first_name) = 'NUM';
```

or this:

```
select * from myTable where lower(first_name) = 'num';
```

Comment: @SP Only links are not a proper answers. Give some explanation or add links as comment.....